# Как восстановить директорию c конфигами /etc/postgresql/?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postgresql, postgresql9.5

По глупости удалил каталог /etc/postgersql/ со всеми конфигами. Пытался purge'ить и просто переустанавливать все, что связано с postgres'ом - ничего не выходит, восстановилась только папка, но без файлов. Очень нужна Ваша помощь!

Comment: Востановите с backup.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql*

sudo rm -r /etc/postgresql/

sudo rm -r /etc/postgresql-common/

sudo rm -r /var/lib/postgresql/

sudo userdel -r postgres

sudo groupdel postgres

sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client postgresql-contrib libpq-dev

### Всем спасибо!